# Using scanf with %[^\n] for a string with no known limit

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

For a uni assignment I have to capture a string (which will be a command later on). The teacher reccomended using fgets but since I don't know the limit, I've decided using that scanf.

The thing is that it's not priting right.

Here's my test code:

```
int main()
{
    char *name1;
    printf("go:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", name1);
    printf("%s xx %s", name1);
}
```

If you have any suggestions with fgets it would be nice too!

Comment: Both `fgets` and `scanf` require you to provide a buffer. So you first have to decide on the buffer size before reading. You could use `getline` which allocates a buffer for you of the appropriate length.

Comment: What you do is _invalid_ because `name1` is not initialized. It has no memory allocated and points at a random memory location where `scanf` will try to store the string. It probably leads to a segmentation fault.

Comment: It will be easier using `fgets` because when the input (perhaps obtained in stages which reallocate the buffer) is complete, the terminating newline will be detectable in the buffer, but with your `scanf` solution it will not.

Comment: An error which was not mentioned is that you are passing 1 parameter to `printf()`, but you are using 2 conversion specifiers (%s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are programming for a PC (and not some embedded device), simply allocate a *really large buffer* (say, 1 MB, or 10, or 100) of which you are sure that it accommodates all conceivable use cases. Memory is incredibly cheap these days, and its not worthwhile to spend resources and complicate your programs in order to save memory. (As an example: How long would you need to be 100% sure that David's solution is completely bug-free? I *probably* would like to write a test for it if it was used in production code.)

Allocate the memory dynamically or statically though; stack space for automatic variables may still be limited. Then use fgets. Still, make sure to handle lines which are too long gracefully. There is no need to concatenate them from chunks as in David's answer: These long lines are either a test case or a data error. You can simply exit with an error message. (If you want to satisfy David Ranieri's sense of good order and principles you can also explicitly free any allocated memory, even though that is entirely redundant on a PC.)

Comment: Still, a good function would return a string of any size provided the operating system has enough memory. For a specific case where you know that the input generally won't go over some MB your approach is perfect. For a general purpose function, it is better to make sure that ANY string can be read by your function as long as the OS can give you the memory.

Comment: _You can simply exit with an error message when you encounter one_. This approach is good for toy programs, in real world you write in a log, you free the used memory in order to avoid memory leaks and a large etcetera... there is a big difference between _exit_ and _exit gracefully_.

Comment: Why would you design a function that exits with an error message when it could do its job perfectly if you tried to reallocate the memory?

Comment: Static storage will _not_ increase the program size (on disk) because it is in the .bss.

Comment: I am not at all talking about program size here. Say you have a buffer that is 10000 bytes. Your user enters a 10001 byte string (including null terminator). Your function would return an error, even though it could reallocate the buffer and 99.99% of the time that memory would be granted by the OS (modern systems have tons of memory) and succeed. It is also UNSAFE to store the first 10000 bytes of the input, because truncation would occur. No matter what static limit you impose on the buffer, you will always be unable to process longer inputs. Leave memory management to the OS!

Comment: @DavidRanieri Writing to a log requires a system specific infrastructure which is beyond this program's scope. Writing to stderr is entirely fine. And yes, one should free resources.

Comment: @DarkAtom I *don't* have a buffer that has 10000 bytes, that's the whole point of my answer ;-).

Comment: @DarkAtom Oh, and the whole reason I don't want to re-allocate is because this is a very simple task which is made hard by a lack of a good library in C. (It's easy in C# or C++, for example.) This is a plea to keep the code simple.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica _Writing to a log requires a system specific infrastructure_ I know, and in this case OP is asking for an assignment, but my point was: it is preferable to spend some time and resources (re)allocating memory than aborting a (maybe critical) program because the buffer was not big enough, where do you put the limit 1000, 10000 bytes?

Comment: @DavidRanieri The input is line based, presumably text; in fact, as given it is interactive, prompting a user on a console for input. Now let's prepare for being non-interactive; it's still text in lines. Let's prepare for really long lines and make it 10MB. Write in your documentation that the program has a line length limit of 10 MB. That would cover many pathological files without any line breaks whatsoever. In my (admittedly not very busy) server's /var/log directory only auth.log has more than 10MB overall (but of course neatly separated in lines).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica 10 MB?  wow ... my stack size is 8 MB, or do you mean be prepared to `malloc(10000000)`?

Comment: Of course @Peter-ReinstateMonica, that's why I'm asking, if you mean 10MB on the stack, it doesn't fit in most systems, if you are talking about the heap it is a waste of RAM for a lot of cases, what do you mean with be prepared and make it 10 MB?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I said "simply allocate a really large buffer (say, 1 MB, or 10, or 100) [...] . Memory is incredibly cheap these days [...] Allocate the memory dynamically or statically though; stack space for automatic variables may still be limited." So yes, I mean use e.g. 10 MB. So yes, the waste is irrelevant. So no, I do not mean 10 MB on the stack. So yes, I do still wonder whether you read my post.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Again, I have read your post and all your comments, memory is cheap, Ok, but not unlimited, we can not waste RAM in this way in C, think for a moment if all programs, commands, daemons do the same, reserve a big amount because memory is cheap ...

Comment: @David If every program I run uses 10 MB I'm fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in the standard C library to safely read an unbounded string. Here is one I wrote by hand (cannot guarantee it has all the safety features, I tried adding what came to my mind):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_string(FILE* stream)
{
    #define INITIAL_BUF_SIZE 100
    size_t size = INITIAL_BUF_SIZE, i = 0;
    int c;
    char* s = malloc(size * sizeof *s);
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while ((c = getc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        s[i++] = c;
        if (i == size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            char* p = realloc(s, size * sizeof *p);
            if (p == NULL)
            {
                free(s);
                return NULL;
            }
            s = p;
        }
    }
    s[i++] = '\0';
    if (i == size)
        return s;
    char* p = realloc(s, i * sizeof *p);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        free(s);
        return NULL;
    }
    return p;
    #undef INITIAL_BUF_SIZE
}

int main(void)
{
    char* name1 = get_string(stdin);
    printf("The string is: %s\n", name1);
    free(name1);
}
```

Note that the returned string must be freed by the caller with `free()` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: `(s[i] = getchar()) != '\n'` puff, you need to check for `EOF` too. Everytime you see `char_variable = getchar()` means it's wrong, `getchar()` returns an `int`.

Comment: I guess you are right, but assuming you are reading from the console input, there are VERY few cases where stdin would return EOF. I will modify it so that it can work with any file though :)

Comment: `are VERY few cases` No? When reading from a file you will encounter EOF, so this happens and happens a lot, quite every time you read from a file. And some people use ctrl+d to send EOF signal.

Comment: I said where *stdin* returns EOF, not *any file*. Don't skip words :) About Ctrl+D: That's what I meant about very few cases.

Comment: @DarkAtom, Kamil is right, just google for "Press CTRL+D to exit" :) or read K&R where all examples uses CTRL+D to exit from the user input

Comment: When I input CTRL+D in my console it doesn't work :) It just inputs a ^D and the output is some nonsense character (but the rest of the input is fine).

Comment: But I understood the idea: always check for EOF, even when reading from stdin :) Everybody learns :P